# Creating Histogram in R from a matrix

Tags: r, histogram

I'm a newbie in R but am currently trying to solve this problem. I am using the `ALL` dataset from `library(ALL)`. Currently I am trying to create a histogram by calculating the average gene expression level for each patient and then plotting them using a histogram. I am able to create a matrix of columns by patient and rows of genes with expression levels as the elements in the matrix using

```
> gene.matrix <- exprs(ALL)
```

From here I am a bit lost though, when trying to create a histogram of just this matrix I do not believe it is charting right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: For more clarification: I believe that the dataset is coming from Bio-conductor, however when I use RStudio I simply type `Library(ALL)`. The following required packages also load

```
Loading required package: Biobase
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel
```

I am using base R for the histogram modeling.

Comment: can you provide us with example data? e.g. `data.frame(patient1=c(1,2,3), patient2=c(2,7,4), row.names=c("geneA","geneB","geneC"))` It would also be good to know what you have tried, i.e. which function for histogram plotting did you use (base R or ggplot), so here your code would also be of much help

Comment: I can't find a library or dataset called ALL

Comment: Hi Both, so the dataset itself is 128 patients and ~13K genes so its quite large. I believe this is using the BioConductor and these are the required packages it loads when I type 
`Library(ALL)
Loading required package: Biobase

Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel `